# How to return an instance of a class with a void member function?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

So I am working on assignment for school involving classes and how to access private public functions. As far as I know I should be able set the values of the class instance that is passed into the functions. However when I run the program it sets the value of the variable to something outside of the values the function specifies. I am not allowed to manipulate the header file to change the value of return type of the function. Could I get a hint to what I am doing wrong?

Here is the definition for the function in class Location. As you can see it has no arguments and thus I can't put `return temp;`so the program knows to save it.

```
void Location::pick() {
    Location temp;
    srand(time(nullptr));
    int tmp = rand() % fieldSize + 1;


    int tmp = rand() % fieldSize + 1;
    switch (tmp) {
    case 1:
        temp.y = 'a';
        break;
    case 2:
        temp.y = 'b';
        break;
    case 3:
        temp.y = 'c';
        break;
    case 4:
        temp.y = 'd';
        break;
    case 5:
        temp.y = 'e';
        break;
    case 6:
        temp.y = 'f';
        break;
    }

}
```

Here is the prototype of the class (If thats the right term for it)

```
    class Location {
public:
    Location(); // void constructor, assigns -1 to X coord, and * to Y coord 
    void pick(); // picks a random location
    void fire(); // asks the user to input coordinates of the next shot
    void print() const; // prints location in format "a1"

    // predicate returns true if the two locations match
    friend bool compare(const Location&, const Location&);

private:
    static const int fieldSize = 6; // the field (ocean) is fieldSize X fieldSize
    int x;  // 1 through fieldSize
    char y; // 'a' through fieldSize
};
```

Here is the test code I am trying to run correctly

```
int main() {

    // srand(time(nullptr)); // random seed
    srand(1); // fixed seed

   //
   // checking location object
   // 

    Location mySpot, userShot;
    mySpot.pick(); // selecting a new random location

    cout << "Randomly selected location is: "; mySpot.print();

    cout << "Input location: ";
    userShot.fire(); // having user input a location

    if (compare(mySpot, userShot))
        cout << "Random location matches user input.\n";
    else
        cout << "Random location does not match user input.\n";
}
```

When the test is ran it makes the value of the initialized variable 
"Randomly selected location is: -858993460╠"
I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Could someone give me a hint or explanation? Is my syntax wrong? Is the logic wrong?

**Here are all the functions I have done so far if you think the problem is  elsewhere**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include "battleship.h"


using std::cin; using std::cout; using std::endl;


Location::Location() {

    int x = -1;
    char y = '*';

}

void Location::pick() {
    Location temp;
    srand(time(nullptr));
    int tmp = rand() % fieldSize + 1;



    switch (tmp) {
    case 1:
        temp.y = 'a';
        break;
    case 2:
        temp.y = 'b';
        break;
    case 3:
        temp.y = 'c';
        break;
    case 4:
        temp.y = 'd';
        break;
    case 5:
        temp.y = 'e';
        break;
    case 6:
        temp.y = 'f';
        break;
    }

}

void Location::fire() {
    Location loc;
    cout << "Input the location you wish to fire at";


    cin >> loc.x;
    cin >> y;
}

void Location::print()const {
    Location loc;
    int x = loc.x;
    char y = loc.y;

    cout << x << y;


}

bool compare(const Location& a, const Location& b) {

    if (a.x == b.x && a.y == b.y){
        return true;
}
    else return false;


}
```

Comment: You should probably modify `this` instance, instead of local variable `temp`.

Comment: The shown `pick()` function creates a brand new object called `temp`, fiddles with it, and returns, accomplishing absolutely nothing, whatsoever. The obvious intent is to modify the method's class's instance, and not some brand new object called `temp`.

Comment: unrelated, call `srand` only once.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That's what I thought but, I wasn't sure so to access the instance of the method would i do pick.y to access the instance of the methods class instance then?

Comment: @Jarod42 thank you I didnt know that.

Comment: This should be explained, in detail, in your C++ book, where you will find much more information than you can from some brief answer on stackoverflow.com. These are basic, fundamental principles of how C++ classes and their methods work, and all of this should be fully explained in any C++ book.

Answer (score 0):

In the `pick()` function, you create another `Location` object(temp), and assign values to that object. What you should do is assign the x and y values to the object calling the `pick()` function, not to another `Location` object defined locally in `pick()`.

```
void Location::pick() {
    srand(time(nullptr));
    int tmp = rand() % fieldSize + 1;

    switch (tmp) {
    case 1:
        this->y = 'a';
        break;
    case 2:
        this->y = 'b';
        break;
    case 3:
        this->y = 'c';
        break;
    case 4:
        this->y = 'd';
        break;
    case 5:
        this->y = 'e';
        break;
    case 6:
        this->y = 'f';
        break;
    }

}
```

You have the same problem in the `print()` function. You could change it to be like this:

```
void Location::print()const {
    cout << this->x << " " << this->y;
}
```

The `this` pointer refers to the current object which called the method. In your case, the `pick()` method has been called by the `mySpot` object created in the main function.

More info on the `this` pointer: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/this-pointer-in-c/